# need to merge 3 columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 3 columns A,B,C and I need to merge the 3 columns and I have applied the forumala `=A1&","&B1&","&C1` the output came as E column I need the output as D column.

[image: screenshot of excel]

Comment: try =CONCATENATE(D1,",",E1) etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following formula will achieve your desired result:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:C1)
```

Textjoin works like concatenate but can have a delimiter as an argument, also it gives you the ability to ignore blank cells, the first argument is the delimiter, the second is the flag to ignore blanks and the third is for the range.

As comments do mention that TEXTJOIN is only available for Office 365 subscribers, a possible alternative would be to build your UDF as below, this will allow you to use the formula above without an Office 365 subscription:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delimiter As String, ignore_empty As Boolean, rng As Range) As String
Dim compiled As String
For Each cell In rng
    If ignore_empty And IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        'nothing
    Else
        compiled = compiled + IIf(compiled = "", "", delimiter) + CStr(cell.Value)
    End If
Next
TEXTJOIN = compiled
End Function
```

Comment: Worth to mention that  *"[TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) is not available in Excel 2016 unless you have an Office 365 subscription. If you are an Office 365 subscriber, make sure you have the latest version of Office."*

Answer (score 3):

Enter this formula into `E1`:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, IF(AND(B1<>"", A1<>""), ",", ""), B1,
    IF(AND(OR(A1<>"", B1<>""), C1<>""), ",", ""), C1)
```

Using [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) might be a cleaner option, but is only available on more recent versions of Excel.

Comment: Note that CONCATENATE is deprecated and here only for compatibility, CONCAT being the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no spaces **within** the cells, then in **D1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1 & " " & B1 & " " & C1)," ",",")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
'Put this code in module and use formula concmulti and select the range 
Function concmulti(slt As Range) As String
Dim str As String
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In slt
str = str & cell.Value & ", "
Next cell
concmulti = str
End Function
```