# How to select range of cells in a string in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I try to select range of cells' values in my excel query.

```
="select [ContactId]  from   [dbo].[Contacts] where username in ('"&A4&"' : '"&A12&"' )"
```

Above is not working.
How should I provide A4:A12 in above string?

I expect my string output would be;

> select [ContactId]  from  [dbo].[tContacts] where username in
>   ('test1',test2,test3,..test14)

Im using microsoft office 2013.

Comment: @BigBen I edited my question with required info

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53391833/9245853) for a UDF version of the `TEXTJOIN` formula, which should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @BigBen TEXTJOIN is not in my excel function

Comment: Exactly. `TEXTJOIN` isn't available in Excel 2013. But you can create a user-defined function to recreate it. Hit Alt-F11, *Insert* > *Module* and copy in the VBA code from the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2013 the function `TEXTJOIN` is not available, so you will either have to join each cell separately, or create a helper column:

Individual joins:

```
="select [ContactId]  from   [dbo].[Contacts] where username in ("&A4&","&A5&","&A6&","&A7&","&A8&","&A9&","&A10&","&A11&","&A12&" )"
```

---

Helper column:

[image]

In B4:

```
=A4
```

In B5 (copy to B12):

```
=B4&","&A5
```

In B14:

```
="select [ContactId]  from   [dbo].[Contacts] where username in ("&B12&")"
```

---

In case you get Excel 2016, then you will be able to use `TEXTJOIN`:

```
="select [ContactId]  from   [dbo].[Contacts] where username in ("&TEXTJOIN(",",0,A4:A12)&")"
```

[image]